# Is the Ethiopian Plateau uplift still ongoing?

Tags: geology, tectonics

The rift zones around the Ethiopian Plateau, Mid Ethiopian Rift, are stil tectonically active since Somalia is separating from Nubia at a rate of 6–7 mm annually<sup>[1]</sup>, and Arabia is rotating counter-clockwise relative Nubia, with continued spreading of the Red Sea Rift and Gulf of Aden rift.

Have there been any measurements on wether the Ethiopian Plateau uplift, which resulted from the tectonic forces in the region over the past 30 million years or so, is still ongoing?

## References

1. Fernandes, Ambrosius, et al (2004). Angular velocities of Nubia and Somalia from continuous GPS data: implications on present-day relative kinematics. Earth Planet. Sci. Lett. 222: 197–208.